# packNGo complains about duplicate files

Tags: code-generation, simulink

when running `packNGo` as a hook at the end of Simulink's code generation, it gives me the following error

```
Error using RTW.BuildInfo/checkForDups (line 35)
The following files have the same file name which cannot be packaged
together in a flat hierarchy:
/path/to/slprj/ert/file
/different/path/to/slprj/ert/file
```

interestingly, only one of these files actually exists.

One difference between this model and some others where packNGo is successful, is that this model has nested layers of referenced models. i.e. referenced models that reference other models. The alleged duplicate files seem to be header files generated from one of these re-referenced models.

Is there perhaps an option I can provide to packNGo, such that it doesn't use a flat hierarchy? Or does anybody know how to inspect BuildInfo to find out why packNGo is looking for files that don't exist? I got as far as:

```
for ii=1:length(buildInfo.ModelRefs)
    buildInfo.ModelRefs(ii).Path
end
```

which returns the version of the path to the header file which actually exists.

Edit: this question resembles [this rather ancient one](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99247-why-do-i-get-the-errors-about-duplicate-files-with-the-packngo-function-in-real-time-workshop-5-1-r), except that I am not generating a Makefile, so the accepted answer does not apply.

Comment: Similar problem (R2016b). I get warnings for duplicates with 
slprj/ert/..../include_X.h
include_X.h (i.e. no path)
The project tree only has one file for each conflict, but packNGo exits with error.
I removed makefile generation and only generate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that despite my best efforts, I left important information out of the question. Instead of just running `packNGo(buildInfo)` as it is shown in the demos, I was running `packNGo(buildInfo, 'minimalHeaders', false)`.

It would appear that using the option `'minimalHeaders', false` in combination with a model that references other models is not possible. In this case, packNGo tries to include headers that don't even exist, and breaks.

So the solution, for now, is to remove this option, and just call `packNGo(buildInfo)`. My initial testing indicates that I am not missing any header files.